# Given a sequence $\{x_k\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let ||x|| denote the Euclidean norm of $x∈\mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

Given a sequence $\{x_k\}$ from k=1 to infinity in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let ||x|| denote the Euclidean norm of $x∈\mathbb{R}^n$.

Recall:

(a) $\{x_k\}$ from k=1 to infinity is bounded if there exists $M$>0 such that we have ||$\{x_k\}$|| ≤ $M$ when every k ≥ 1.

(b) $\{x_k\}$ from k=1 to infinity is bounded if there exists $L_{i}$ > 0, $i$ =1,...,$n$ such that for every $i$=1,...,n, we have |$x_{ki}$| ≤ $L_{i}$ when k≥1.

Prove that (a) <--> (b).

Ideas anyone?

Comment: $ (a) \Rightarrow  (b)$ is quite easy, enough to take  all $L_i$ to be equal to  $M$.  For the reverse order, take  $M=max \{L_i; i=1,\cdots n \}$ .

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{ e_1, \dots, e_n \}$ be a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then, for every vector $x_k$ from the sequence $\{ x_k \}$, there exist (real or complex) numbers $x_{k}^{1}, \dots, x_{k}^{n} $ such that 
\begin{equation}
x_k = \sum_{l=1}^{n} x_{k}^{l} e_l.
\end{equation}
Define the norm $\lvert \cdot \rvert_1 \, \colon \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ by 
\begin{equation}
\lvert x \rvert_1 = \sum_{l=1}^{n} \lvert x^{l} \rvert,
\end{equation}
where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is given by $x = \sum_{l=1}^{n} x^{l} e_l$.

Since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a finite dimensional vector space, both norms $\lvert \cdot \rvert_1$ and $\lvert \lvert \cdot \rvert \rvert$ are equivalent; in particular, there exist constants $C_1, C_2 > 0$ such that
\begin{equation}
C_1 \lvert \lvert x \rvert \rvert \leq \lvert x \rvert_1 \leq C_2 \lvert \lvert x \rvert \rvert,
\end{equation}
for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

We are now ready to prove the claim. Let us start with $(a) \Rightarrow (b)$: by the very definition of the norm $\lvert \cdot \rvert_1$, we find that
\begin{equation}
\lvert x_{k}^{i} \rvert \leq \sum_{l=1}^{n} \lvert x_{k}^{l} \rvert = \lvert x_k \rvert_1 \leq C_2 \lvert \lvert x_k \rvert \rvert \leq C_2 M
\end{equation}
for all $i \in \{1, \dots, n \}$. Thus, $\{ x_k \}$ is a bounded sequence.

Conversely, if 
\begin{equation}
\lvert x_{k}^{i} \rvert \leq L_i,
\end{equation}
for all $i \in \{ 1, \dots, n \}$ and $k \geq 1$, then
\begin{equation}
\lvert x_k \rvert_1 = \sum_{l=1}^{n} \lvert x_{k}^{l} \rvert \leq \sum_{l=0}^{n} L_l \leq n \max \{ L_1, \dots, L_n \}.
\end{equation}
Hence, we find that
\begin{equation}
\lvert \lvert x_k \rvert \rvert \leq \frac{1}{C_1} \lvert x_k \rvert_1 \leq \frac{n}{C_1} \max \{ L_1 \dots, L_n \}. 
\end{equation}
That is, $\{ x_k \}$ is a bounded sequence.